# Overwriting CSS properties in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change the look of Twitter Bootstrap. I basically know how this works and have everything set up & working.

By default, the `.navbar-inner` has a border radius. See how it is declared below - they used prefixes.

```
.navbar-inner {
  min-height: 40px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f2f2f2);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#ffffff), to(#f2f2f2));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f2f2f2);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f2f2f2);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #f2f2f2);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px;
          border-radius: 4px;
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff', endColorstr='#fff2f2f2', GradientType=0);
  *zoom: 1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.065);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.065);
          box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.065);
}
```

Now let's say I don't want that `border-radius`. Do I have to write it like this

```
.navbar-inner {
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

or like this

```
.navbar-inner {
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
     -moz-border-radius: 0;
          border-radius: 0;
}
```

to ensure maximum browser compatibility?

Using the first option works for me and it looks nicer than with all the prefixes, but I am worried that some browsers won't understand it.

Comment: Check here to see which browsers these vendor prefixes are actually needed for, you might be surprised: http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius

Comment: I don't know if it's just me, but I can't find any info on the prefixes there. However, this resource says it can be safely used without prefixes, so I wonder why they still use prefixes at all. http://html5please.com/#border-radius But that's another question I guess.

Comment: Click "Show all versions". Any cell that has `-prefix` in it means that version of that browser requires it (there are not many nowadays). I would actually say both of those prefixes for border radius aren't necessary at all, but it's up to you.

Comment: You might want to write your own 'mixin' ... http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#mixins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the prefixes if you want to cover all of the older browsers. That is the reason bootstrap has included prefixes to begin with.

If you only use the un-prefixed version, the older browsers that implemented only the prefixed versions will not interpret the un-prefixed version correctly and will not be changed / zeroed out.